# Trying to build a Wien bridge oscillator, but can't make the oscillations work.

Tags: transistors, oscillator, wien-bridge

[image]

I built this circuit to have oscillations between 20kHz to 30kHz. Unfortunately the oscillations come out very tiny and very irregular.

What should I modify or add and why to make the oscillations work?

Comment: Are those tiny oscillations at the correct frequency?

Comment: The oscillations are at the correct frequency.

Comment: For what reason you are using 6 BJTs and one Fet? You only need an amplification factor (high input resistance) slightly above +3, thats all!

Comment: I don't really know why I'm using the 6 BJTs. I just searched for an OPAMP schematic. I removed the FET.

Comment: If you want an op amp, either purchase one such as the LM358 or LF411 or use a circuit which is for discrete components. The schematic above uses current mirrors to achieve biasing (and as an active load, but that's a good idea in any case) but this is only because it is less expensive to manufacture transistors on an IC than resistors. Analog IC designers go out of their way to avoid resistors. You don't have to, so I would recommend avoiding op-amp schematics like this. As for finding one that is particularly for discrete components, maybe look into diff amps with active loads.

Comment: The college doesn't allow us to use OPAMPs. If I could've used one, this would have been long finished.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Q8 the JFET. That current upsets the current mirror Q5/Q6.

And **ADD** a buffer (a JFET works fine) from top of R10 (sets the gain) to C1.

Your WEIN network demands way too much current for what the opamp can provide.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQxszx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I added the JFET to the top of R10 and removed Q8. I assume you meant that the gate should be connected to R10.

Same thing happened. I think I will make another design for the OPAMP, but how do I know if it can provide enough current t the network?

Comment: you'll need a pulldown resistor on the source of JFET.